# When dual-wielding swords, which armor is more useful?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

When dual wielding swords, which armor type is better to use; Light armor or Heavy armor?

Comment: There is no objective answer.

Comment: Actually, the objective answer is "neither".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's personal preference, really. Without perk investment, it's easier to hit the armor cap with heavy armor, but if you invest in it, Light Armor is just as good, and less cumbersome to boot.

Given that you won't have the armor from the shield though, you may want to stick with heavy armor, at least starting out, since you're not going to be able to mitigate any damage by blocking - your armor and dodging is all you've got.